# SELECT either id = 0 or id = 555 but not both - ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, select, xor

Seems like Oracle is lacking the XOR operator and I can't figure out how make the following query select rows with *ID=0* when a row with *ID=555* is not found

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (id = 0 or id = 555)
```

This gives me rows with id 0 and 555 but I don't want the rows with *ID=0* if there are matching rows with the same *KEY* and *ID=555*

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/436417/xor-operator

Comment: I don't see how an exclusive-OR would help here, since it's already not possible for ID to be both 0 and 555 at the same time. It seems you want rows where ID = 0 and no row exists where ID = 555, or rows where ID is 555 and no row exists where ID = 0. This is already more or less SQL syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `not exists` as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM table t 
 WHERE id = 0 
   AND NOT EXISTS 
       (select 1 from table tt
         where tt.key = t.key and tt.id = 55)
```